# php web application and strange 404 error (something wrong with Apache ?)

Tags: php, apache, ontowiki

I have downloaded a php web application from the web (OntoWiki).
After the installation I've tried it and it works fine on my Ubuntu 10.10, but when I try to install it on CentOS Linux, the only page that works is the home page (index.php).
If i try to change the page, the browser sends me a 404 error page (page not found).
Instead if i try to change the URL with the "index.php" as prefix it works fine.
Example:

- `localhost/app/index.php/directory` -> works
- `localhost/app/directory` -> doesn't work (404 error)

Why does this happen? On the PC where the program works i have the URL like: `host/application` but everything works fine.

Is there an Apache Configuration problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Check you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your CentOS server.

Answer (score 2):

Active the Apache rewrite module:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart Apache.

Answer (score 2):

In an application like OntoWiki, all requests are directed through `index.php`. An `.htaccess` file accompanies the project including `RewriteRule`'s to map a path like `/directory` to `/index.php/directory`.

Apache's `mod_rewrite` module must be installed and enabled for the host in order for the RewriteRules to be applied. It sounds like you have it disabled on your CentOS box and enabled locally.

Comment: My WebApp is located at the folder /home/<user>/public_html  so i should i decomment this part? #<Directory /home/*/public_html>
#    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit All
#    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
#    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
#        Order allow,deny
#        Allow from all
#    </Limit>
#    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
#        Order deny,allow
#        Deny from all
#    </LimitExcept>
#</Directory>

Comment: `AllowOverride` is set to 'None' by default. Setting it to at least `FileInfo` for that `<Directory ...>` may be necessary after `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: How can i enable mod_rewrite in centOS?

Comment: @vinnylinux's comment tells you how. Google is also your friend "how to enable mod_rewrite in CentOS".

Comment: Last question (i hope :P ): i've enabled mod_rewrite, and after decommented that part above (in my httpd.conf), now i have an error 404 at the main page (located at host/ontowiki) with index.php not found. But if i type the complete url (http://.../~user/ontowiki/index.php) the page work but still not working the link of this page. Should i change the symbol '*' with my username in the httpd.conf configuration file on the tag <Directory>?

Comment: The mapping of a directory to some `index.*` file is done through the `dir_module` which you must also make sure is enabled *(though it more than likely is)*. It sounds like you need a `DirectoryIndex` directive like `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` added to your `<Directory ...>`'s body. Currently `dir_module` is ignoring `index.php`.

Comment: In the httpd.conf i have the command "DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php" some rows down the <Directory /home/*/public_html>...</Directory> block. So you are telling me to copy it and paste it inside the <Directory /home/*/public_html> block? (I want to be sure, because i am not the server administrator, so every change must be done by another person).

Comment: No, that's not what I'm telling you; if you already have a `DirectoryIndex` containing `index.php` in the main section of the `httpd.conf` that should be enough. Have you been restarting apache after each of the changes to `httpd.conf`? Does a `404` error also come when putting an `index.html` page into the ontowiki directory? Are you sure `dir_module` is enabled? Do you have the same issue for all other hosts running on this Apache install?

Comment: 1) Yes i've restarted Apache 2) even if i put a index.HTML file, the browser return that he can't find a index.PHP file (i dont know if this is due to that commands in .htaccess file "    RewriteRule ^favicon\.(.*)$ application/favicon.$1
    RewriteRule !((extensions|libraries).*|\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|php|swf|json))$ index.php"     3) i have "mod_dir" enabled in my "loaded modules" of Apache  4) I dont know for other hosts

Comment: 4) if i create a new folder on public_html with a index.php file, it works

Comment: Yeah, we should have removed the contents of the .htaccess file earlier to rule that out. Looking at https://github.com/AKSW/OntoWiki/blob/develop/.htaccess, do you have RewriteBase set properly?

Comment: I didn't edit my .htaccess file until now, what should i put inside RewriteBase?